# Problemas al seleccionar colunmas de otra tabla, laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

tengo la siguiente consulta.

```
 $conteoconsejales = usuarios::join('advice', 'usuarios.conse_id', '=' , 
                                    'advice.ida')
                              ->where('conse_id',$valorconse)              
                              ->where('asignacion', '<>', '')              
                              ->select('user_id')
                              ->get();
```

Mi proposito es selecionar solo las columnas que quiero mostrar, el problema es que quiero incluir la columna que extraigo en el join, dentro del select, pero no se si esto se puede hacer, si por ejemplo lo hago, agregando esta columna usuarios.conse_id en el select().

```
 $conteoconsejales = usuarios::join('advice', 'usuarios.conse_id', '=' , 
                                    'advice.ida')                          
                             ->where('conse_id',$valorconse)               
                             ->where('asignacion', '<>', '')               
                             ->select('user_id', usuarios.conse_id)
                             ->get();
```

Me trae el id, pero quiero que me traiga es el nombre, osea advice_candidate de la tabla advice, tal cual como si realizara el join.

```
join('advice', 'usuarios.conse_id', '=' , 'advice.ida')
```

Pero no puedo meter un join dentro del select? esto se podra?

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo hace con Eloquent? es mucho más fácil.

Comment: Bueno Shaz, creo que ya se como.

Comment: usuarios::join('assembly', 'usuarios.asam_id', '=' , 'assembly.idas')->where('asam_id',$valorasam)->where('asignacion', '<>', '')->select('user_id', 'user_id', 'usuario_ad', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'cedula', 'telefonos', 'direccion', 'barrio', 'lugar_votacion', 'mesa_votacion', 'email', 'ciudad','asignacion','estado', 'advice.advice_candidate')->get();

Comment: Solo era selecionar la columna que yo queria de esa otra tabla asi, 'advice.advice_candidate'

Comment: No me refería a eso, aún así sigue siendo una consulta inoficiosa para algo que puede hacerse muy fácil con Eloquent.